# How to make an environment variable available for a python program using os.environ module?

Tags: python, environment-variables, bashrc

I'm just new in this site and new to all the GNU/Linux environment, I'm trying to access to an environment variable from a python program that I wrote in PyCharm, I created it but I the the variable doesn`t appears in my python program.

This is what I already have done:

- created an environment variable in `.bashrc` (when I verify, the variable appears me in the terminal)
- This is what I have typed in my .bashrc file:

  `export API_KEY=my_api_key_here`
- `import os` package in my Python program
- use the `os.environ` module in my program (to check if my environment variable appears)

I don't really know where to define my environment variables, on **.bashrc** or **.profile** files, (that two option are the only ones that appears me)

In short I want to have access to my own defined environment variables from my program.

I hope you can help me please! And tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you created an *environment variable*, not just a plain shell variable? Please [edit] your question to show the relevant line(s) of your .bashrc file

Comment: Did you `export` the variable?

Comment: Yes, I typed it as shown above

Comment: Can you see the variable in the shell,before starting python ? Try `echo $API_KEY`

Comment: Yes, in fact I checked it before I tried to use it in PyCharm do you think is something related with global / user variables?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, you usually put it in `.bashrc`, because users usually use bash. If you've verified that it exists in the terminal, probably you forgot to `export` it. Without exporting it, it exists only in your current terminal, not in your python script nor any program you calls from the terminal.

This is an example python code named `envi.py`:

```py
import os
print(os.environ['MYVAR'])
```

First, let's test it directly in terminal:

```bsh
export MYVAR="my value"
python3 envi.py
# the output should be: my value
```

If you're satisfied with the result, you can then put `export MYVAR="my value"` in `.bashrc`, open a new terminal, and then run your python script.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I already did what you mentioned above and It got well I did not have any problem, then I typed the same on .basrc (export API_KEY=my_api_key_here) and I tried to run my code from PyCharm but I`m still receiving the error message "raise KeyError(key) from None KeyError: 'API_KEY' ".

Note: I`m not running my python program from terminal, I`m running it from PyCharm just to check if my code has not any problem so far and I got this problem.
THANK YOU!

Comment: @ALDOFLORESAGUAYO I've not used pycharm for a long time. It seems pycharm doesn't read .bashrc, and setting `API_KEY` seems more suitable to be done in pycharm settings, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22899916/1197317) out. May it helps.

Comment: I really appreciated it, I will try it and if I get some favorable results I will let you know again thanks a lot!

Comment: When using pycharm, the environment variables have to be defined in "Run/Debug Configurations" dialog. In the python configuration inside the region "Environment" you can define environment variables that are passed to the program.